# Can't set a new innerHTML for an element with JS in .HTA page

Tags: javascript, wsh, hta

I'm trying to set a new innerHTML property for the head element of my .HTA page for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var headHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
var headHTML = headHTML.replace('Some','Another');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = headHTML;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get the error:

> Could not set the innerHTML property. Invalid target element for this
>   operation.

Why and how to resolve the problem?

ps. the title is just an example. I need to replace innerHTMLs of different elements in head and body.

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title instead

Comment: No, the title is just an example. I need to replace innerHTMLs of different elements in head and body

Comment: It would probably help if you explained what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

This is more IE specific issue than an HTA issue. In IE, `innerHTML` of `head` and `title` elements is read-only ([among some other elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms533897(v=vs.94))). However, elements can be appended to `head`. For example, create a link element to add a stylesheet to the document:

```
var elem = document.createElement('link');
elem.rel = 'stylesheet';
elem.type = 'text/css';
elem.href = '....';
document.documentElement.appendChild(elem);
```

`appendChild` method can be used to add elements to `document.body` as well.

See [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) at MDN.

Comment: Actually, `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<some code>'` works in IE11, but not in IE9 or lower. I've just tested it

Comment: Well, MS documentation says the inner html of the head element is read-only ... And what's the point to redefine the entire head anyway? Notice, that `+=` is not an appending operator, it redefines its operand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put your `JS` in

```
<script language="javascript">

</script>
```